# How to open colorbox using search form

Tags: php, html, colorbox

The search form code below needs to open a colorbox window with the html search results inside. It works -as is- while redirecting to the search results page, but I would like to put the search results inside a colorbox instead.

What I need is code inside the search form, at the very bottom, that will do that. Thank you!

```
<form class="form" action="http://mydomain.com/?UserName=" method="get">
            <input type="text" id="search" name="UserName" value="UserName" onfocus="if (this.value == 'UserName') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'UserName';}">
<input type="submit" value="Search" id="submit"></form>
```

Comment: Didn't got your question

Comment: I think he wants to open a color box with the results..?